# Php / Sql Convert Calender week

Tags: php, date

I got this:

```
/**
 * current calenderweek
 */
$date = new DateTime();     
echo $date->format('W');
/**
 * Update Database with current Calenderweek
 */

    ...
        $data = array(
            'id'        => $result['id'],
            'firstname' => $firstname,
            'lastname'  => $lastname,
            'calender_week' => $date->format('W')
        );
```

I basically put the current calender week ( which is now 40 ) into my database as an integer.

Now, is there any way to convert this value to the date in which the weeks started and ended, in my case the starting day would be

> monday 28.09.2015

and the end would be

> sunday 04.10.2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$week = 40;
$year = 2015;

$time = mktime(0,0,0,1,1,$year) + ($week * 7 *24 * 60 * 60);
$time = $time - ((date('N', $time) - 1) * 24 * 60 * 60);

$monday = date('D d-M-Y', $time);
$sunday = date('D d-M-Y', $time + (6 * 24 * 60 * 60));

echo $monday . ' - ' . $sunday;
```